# Hardrive is full with 0 space left can't access admin account

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and after all the packages are installed and the system restarted when I log into the admin account I cannot  see anything save for a black screen, when I log out and login through the Guest account Im getting an error saying "You have 0 space in your hardrive". Is there a way to rectify this or delete files from the main partition through the guest account?

Comment: Is that like a bug or you actually expected to have no disk space left? How much disk are you giving to it?

Comment: Are you able to boot into terminal mode? (Ctrl+Alt+F2) If so, try running 'sudo fdisk -l' and paste the output here.

Answer (score 1):

- During boot up does it try to start a graphical environment then hang?

If so, you should be able to press `Control-Alt-F1` to break out to a text terminal session. This might let you login.  Press `Alt-F7` to return to your graphical environment.

- Original install media (DVD/CD/USB)

Lastly, you may have to bite the bullet and boot from your original install media to get a recovery session and clean up some space on your boot drive.